# team foundation server bug tracking tools

Tags: visual-studio-2008, tfs, bug-tracking, tfs-workitem

I am new to TFS and am told that TFS (VS 2008) has an internal bug tracking system. I have used open source bug tracking systems before but want to work with TFS now.
If anyone knows or has links to any readin bout this please answer this question

Answer (score 6):

Here are some [walkthroughs for work item tracking in TFS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181268(VS.80).aspx).  This should help get you started.  I also recommend the book Software Engineering with Microsoft Visual STudio Team System by Guckenheimer, et. al.